# Why do I need an Azure On-Premises Data Gateway for my Azure Analysis Service?

Tags: azure, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

So I have this Azure Analysis Service where the data source of the cube points to an external (on prem) SQL Server database. For some reason it won't connect to it even when I have the proper firewall changes in place.

When processing the cube it complains that I need to install the on-premises data gateway.

So my question is: Is the on-premises data gateway mandatory for connecting to other sources outside Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Per docs, all non-Azure data sources require the on-premises data gateway:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource

As to why, it's unusual and not recommended that you would expose your on-premises SQL Server for direct connection from the internet.

Comment: In our situation only certain azure vnets attached to our analysis services are aloud to connect to the on prem sql server. For us the data gateway adds nothing.

Comment: But Azure Analysis Services, itself, is not on your VNet.  It's got a public IP, and wouldn't be routed through your private networks.

Comment: True but that's something different. It's okay that azure analysis services is public facing. But the data source for the cube isn't. So therefor the gateway for us is necessary evil.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: I'm lost by your comment: The data source for Azure Analysis Services is NOT going to be from an on-prem SQL. Is it?! Because as per your docs, to create a data model in Azure Analysis Services, you have to use SSDT. That's the only way to upload it. And because AAS provides a public URL to that data model, then anyone with internet access can read from it. So why on earth does it need an on premises GW for?!!!!

Comment: AAS needs to load data. SSDT only uploads the model metadata.